# How to programmatically determine the AWS-optimized ECS image for a given region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ami

I want to script EC2 creation that would join a given ECS cluster, but need to specify an AMI. I can see that I can find an AMI in the AWS documentation, but the URL requires a login to the console and thus isn't convenient to screen-scrape. Is there any other recommended resource to determine the suggested AMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [retrieve the recommended AMI from the Systems Manager Parameter Store API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/retrieve-ecs-optimized_AMI.html) or [subscribe to an SNS topic for notifications when new AMIs are released](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS-AMI-SubscribeTopic.html).

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out ASAP.